# How should I handle a PC attempting to strangle a creature?

Tags: grapple, pathfinder-2e

Last session, one of my PCs succeeded on a grapple check against a rust monster and wanted to strangle it in retribution for damaging the PC's sword, which has sentimental value.

There are suffocation rules on page 478 of the Core Rulebook, but I haven't been able to find anything on strangulation, which should take into account cutting off blood flow to the brain (for creatures with both blood and a brain).

The scene that played out as the rust monster was bombarded with spells by the other PCs while being strangled was quite entertaining, and I expect it will happen again. What would be a good way to handle this situation mechanically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pathfinder 2e has no method to strangle yet.

There are no PC abilities that allow PC's to strangle targets yet. If you wish to allow it, the rules related to [Suffocation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=468) work well enough and are significantly more harsh [than in other RPG's](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Suffocation&Category=Environmental%20Rules), so I would not add anything to them to account for blood blockage or similar.

> You can hold your breath for a number of rounds equal to 5 + your Constitution modifier. Reduce your remaining air by 1 round at the end of each of your turns, or by 2 if you attacked or cast any spells that turn. You also lose 1 round worth of air each time you are critically hit or critically fail a save against a damaging effect. If you speak (including casting spells with verbal components or activating items with command components) you lose all remaining air.

### There is some guidance in Monster abilities

The [Dero Strangler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=106)'s namesake ability only adds damage to their Grabbing.

> Strangle [Single Action] (attack, nonlethal) **Requirement** The dero must have two free hands, or be wielding an aklys and have one hand free. **Effect** The dero attempts an Athletics check to Grab with a +2 circumstance bonus. On a success, the target takes 1d6+6 bludgeoning damage. Double the damage on a critical success.

---

I would personally not allow PC's to Strangle without some special ability. Grappling is fairly easy to accomplish (as most things are in 2e) and balanced around the Conditions already included in the ability. I might allow them to Strangle for Fists damage on a Critical Success instead of applying Restrained; more likely, I would just narrate that they are doing it but apply no actual mechanical benefit.